# Singleton pattern in database connection in .net

Tags: design-patterns, c#-4.0, singleton

Have a doubt in my project the database connection object is created via singleton pattern as opening and closing connection is heavy operation but i have doubt shouldn't we dispose of the object what is the use of keeping it alive as closing connection frees memory

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, there is **no** point in holding onto a connection to your db server. All DB clients[ADO.NET, ODBC, Jdbc,etc] support `connection pool` mechanism. You are better off to rely on that and use that properly, than to keep a singleton connection object to your database.

Comment: What about mongo db does it also provide connection pool this singleton was used with momgodb

Comment: A simple Google search says MongoDb does provide `connection pool`, see [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/connection-pool-overview/) page.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good idea as if singleton is not correctly implemented, then one thread can dispose the connection, however the another thread can try to execute some command.

There is [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?redirectedfrom=MSDN) when you call `new SqlConnection()` or `connection.Open()`

So it is better to create new connection to take advantage of connection pooling.